# Implicit Rules in Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

hi i want to do a Makefile in linux that will take all  the .cpp files in the dir compile them
and create one .o file that i can active how i can do it with Implicit Rules

thanks
mati

Comment: Don't you mean one `.a` or `.so` file?

Comment: There will be n .o files for n .cpp files. I think you are talking about .so. Use ar rcs for generating libs

Answer (score 1):

Implicit rules will help you create the object files, but combining them together will have to be done explicitly (as it is something that is rarely done).

```
OBJ = a.o b.o

big.o : ${OBJ}
    ${LD} -r -o $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can try following method after properly defined the variables:

```
.o: .cpp
    $(CPP) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: $(CPP) and $(CPPFLAGS) are for the preprocessor, not the compiler. I think you meant $(CXX) and $(CXXFLAGS).